# Can I enable password asterisks during login on Ubuntu server?

Tags: authentication, passwords, ubuntu-20.04, iso

I’m building a custom ISO file for Ubuntu 20.04 . Is it possible to show asterisks for each password char at the initial login into Ubuntu server?
Not making password asterisks visible in Ubuntu terminal after the `sudo` command, but in the login promt.

I used the `sudo visudo` command to edit `/etc/sudoers` file and to add `pwfeedback` to defaults, but it only allows asterisks while using `sudo` in the command line.